# Конструктор базового класса с интерфейсом

Tags: c#, .net

Не могу провести базовый конструктор с интерфейсом через наследованный. Пишет ошибку про приведения типов. В чем проблема?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А как вы представляете себе преобразование коллекции в число?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, скорее всего просто опечатка в имени класса из-за незнания различий

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка заключается в том, что в базовом классе нет соответствующего конструктора.

Поэтом нужно либо вызывать другой конструктор, либо передавать другой параметр.

---

Вместо общего класса [`Queue`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.queue?view=netcore-3.1), надо было использовать generic класс [`Queue<T>`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.queue-1?view=netcore-3.1), у которого есть необходимый конструктор, тогда проблемы из вопрос не было бы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Так же вместо `IEnumerable<T>` можно было использовать любой тип реализующий `ICollection`, в этом случае тоже работало бы.